# Transform pptx file to jpg with VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a folder full of pptx files, and a code base that generates pptx files from a table in excel, via VBA, I need to put in this code a step in which I transform the pptx file into jpg, it can be after creating the file or during, follow code below

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GerarPPTS()

    Dim tb As ListObject 'ListObject é uma tabela
    Dim Linha As ListRow
    
    Dim ppt             As Object 'PowerPoint.Application
    Dim apresentacao As Object 'PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim slide       As Object 'PowerPoint.slide
    Dim sp          As Object 'PowerPoint.Shape
    
    'Set o objeto Tabela que é Objeto de lista
    Set tb = wsInicio.ListObjects("tbPEssoas")
    
    'Gerar um PPT APLICAÇÂo
    Set ppt = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application") 'ew PowerPoint.Application
    ppt.Visible = True
         
    'Loopar as linhas da tabela
    For Each Linha In tb.ListRows
        
         'Criando uma Apresentação
         'Baseada num modelo
         Set apresentacao = ppt.Presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ANIVERSARIANTE Auto.pptx")
        'Loopar os Slides trocando as variaveis
        'do PPT pelos valores do Excel
    
        'Tenta alterar o texto de TODOS
        'os shapes e se der erro continua
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each slide In apresentacao.Slides
            For Each sp In slide.Shapes
                sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = VBA.Replace(sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "@NOME", Linha.Range(1, 1))
                sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = VBA.Replace(sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "@DATA", Linha.Range(1, 2))
            
            Next sp
        Next slide
        'Desliga o tratamento de erro malucop
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        'SALVA O ARQUIVO NO LUGAR DESEJADO
        apresentacao.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Linha.Range(1, 1) & ".pptx"
        VBA.DoEvents
    Next Linha
   
    'FECHA O POWERPOINT
    ppt.Quit
    Set ppt = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use PowerPoint vba to save as jpg?  ` Sub saveAs()`
    `Dim p As Presentation`
    `Set p = ActivePresentation`
    `p.saveAs "C:\Users\...\SomeFolder", ppSaveAsJPG, msoTrue`
`End Sub`

Comment: gives compilation error

"expected error: ="

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add one line of code; this will export slide 1 as `Auto_1.JPG`, slide 2 as `Auto_2.JPG` and so on.
Doing it slide by slide using .Export allows you to specify the JPG resolution you want and the names of the exported JPGs (`.SaveAs` doesn't permit this).

A suggestion: don't use the name of PPT objects for variable names; for example, instead of slide, use `sl` or (more commonly) `oSl` or `oSld` (the o indicates that it's an object)

```
For Each slide In apresentacao.Slides
    For Each sp In slide.Shapes
        sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
        VBA.Replace(sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "@NOME", Linha.Range(1, 1))
                sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
        VBA.Replace(sp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "@DATA", Linha.Range(1, 2))
    Next sp
    'ADD THIS:
    Dim sPath as String
    sPath = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" ' Assuming Windows, not Mac
    Call slide.Export(sPath & "Auto_" & cstr(slide.slideindex) _
        & ".JPG", "JPG", 1024, 768)
Next slide
```

Comment: Not saving, shouldn't I assign a directory to save in code?

Comment: still without saving

Comment: Yes, you need to dim sPath as string and set it to the directory you want to save to, terminated with a \